# Login to LinkedIn by using username and password failed

Tags: java, httpclient, linkedin-api, jsoup

LinkedIn uses oauth to login to its api.There is no way to login to api in server.I tried to use http request to login into linkedin and get `oauth_verifier`,but I got response like this

> We’re sorry, there was a problem with
>   your request. Please make sure you
>   have cookies enabled and try again.
>
> Or follow this link to return to the
>   home page.

I have analyze the communicate between my browser and server many times,but still could't find why

```
  public boolean Login(String user, String pass, String url) {
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient;
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 100);
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

        // Create and initialize scheme registry
        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));
        // Create an HttpClient with the ThreadSafeClientConnManager.
        // This connection manager must be used if more than one thread will
        // be using the HttpClient.
        ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);

        String loginHTML = httpSession.Get(url);

        for (Cookie c : httpSession.cs.getCookies()) {
            httpclient.getCookieStore().addCookie(c);
        }

        Document doc = Session.GetDocument(loginHTML, url);
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String postURL = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "oauthAuthorizeForm").get(0).absUrl("action");
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpEntity entity;
        HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(postURL);
        List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        hm.put("session_login", user);
        hm.put("session_password", pass);
        hm.put("duration", "0");
        hm.put("authorize", "Ok, I&apos;ll Allow It");
        hm.put("extra", doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "extra").get(0).attr("value"));
        hm.put("access", doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "access").get(0).attr("value"));
        hm.put("agree", "true");
        hm.put("oauth_token", doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "oauth_token").get(0).attr("value"));
        hm.put("appId", doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "appId").get(0).attr("value"));
        hm.put("csrfToken", doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "csrfToken").get(0).attr("value"));
        hm.put("sourceAlias", doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "sourceAlias").get(0).attr("value") + "session_login=" + user);


        for (Entry<String, String> i : hm.entrySet()) {
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair(i.getKey(), new String(i.getValue().getBytes(), "utf-8")));
        }
        hm.put("sourceAlias", doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("name", "sourceAlias").get(0).attr("value"));
        for (Entry<String, String> i : hm.entrySet()) {
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair(i.getKey(), new String(i.getValue().getBytes(), "utf-8")));
        }

        httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
        httpost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Shisoft NetFusion");
        response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
        entity = response.getEntity();


        Header headers[] = response.getHeaders("location");
        for (Header h : headers) {
            if (!h.getValue().isEmpty()) {
                String newurl = h.getValue();
                String oauthVerifier = newurl.split("oauth_verifier=")[1].split("&")[0];
                accessToken = oauthService.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, oauthVerifier);
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (entity != null) {
            String resHTML = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            //entity.getContent().close();
            httpost.abort();
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().closeExpiredConnections();
        }

        httpost.abort();
        return false;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClassLinkedIn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return false;
}
```

the url is AuthorizationUr
httpSession.Get(url); gets the login page and cookies.

Comment: Hey Shisoft have you solved this problem?
can you give me some suggestion for I am also getting same problem. Thx

Comment: I tried your answer but I think I am not getting correct jar.
I am using HtmlUnit jar but getting an exception here 
'final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage(url);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use HTMLUnit solved this issue.

```
   public boolean Login(String user, String pass, String url) {
        try {
            final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

            // Get the first page
            final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage(url);

            // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form,
            // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
            final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("oauthAuthorizeForm");

            final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("authorize");
            final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("session_login");
            final HtmlPasswordInput textField2 = form.getInputByName("session_password");
            // Change the value of the text field
            textField.setValueAttribute(user);
            textField2.setValueAttribute(pass);

            // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.

            final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
            String newurl = page2.getUrl().toString();
            String oauthVerifier = newurl.split("oauth_verifier=")[1].split("&")[0];
            accessToken = oauthService.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, oauthVerifier);

            webClient.closeAllWindows();
            logined = true;
            return true;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClassLinkedIn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But remember,you need to use the last version of HTMLUnit,not the release on sf.net
This also is not a perfect solution.It works,but cost a lot on javascript\css inside the webpages and others

Comment: I am also getting that same problem I am trying to log using httpclient also posting all values which is required. 
but its showing "Please enter a valid email address."
after post all values and cookies.
I have checked email id is correct.
can you tall me which jar we will need to use for this example?
can you give me some more code?