# Linkedin authentication request error

Tags: session-cookies, linkedin-api

so I'm implementing the option to login with your linkedin account, but I find that sometimes you will get a request error saying:

> Request Error
>
> We’re sorry, there was a problem with your request. Please make sure you have cookies enabled and try again.
>
> Or follow this link to return to the home page.

So I did some digging and I found that this error pops up if you don't have a certain cookie from linkedin called JSESSIONID. This is only created when you go to linkedin.com, but not my extension authentication page. Anyone have an explanation and a solution?

Thanks

Comment: I notice that if you send people to api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorize... you get this error. You should be sending people to www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorize. It's really annoying how linked in serve you a page that looks right from the api.linkedin.com server, but won't work!

Comment: @Tapp, can you upvote the accepted answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a work around:

[link to an approved solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5325247/3871208)

it provides a java implementation, and they point out it is more about the version of the library you are using.

hopefully it helps.